# How does R handle Observation fewer than Variable problem in PCA

Tags: r, regression, pca, prediction, partial-least-squares

Got a dataset of 63 observations of 900 variables. The Variable data is arranged as 63x900.
I'm trying to build a prediction model based on this dataset. Three methods have been tried: PCR, PLSR, and Random Forest Regression. 
PCA returned a 63x63 matrix, which obviously something happened there which I dont know why. I tried then transpose the Variable matrix and PCA, and then transposed it back for regression. 
By using the Root Mean Square Error with validation data, I tested different models accuracy with increasing PCs. It gave a totally different result, which suggests the PCs are also different.
I want to ask how does R handle such problem when observation is fewer than variable dimensions in PCA. Some further exploration and comparison I found PLSR may also have the same problem. Random Forest however gives a similar RMSE result with the transposed PCA regression, which gives me a really challenge to decide which one is correct.
[image: 63PCs model]

63PCs model RMSE

[image: transposed PC model]

Transposed PC model RMSE

Comment: Well, in a m x n sized matrix PCA returns scores with min([m,n]) columns. That is because the rest of the eigenvalues(or the explained variance) is zero.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I found the constraint you mentioned in the prcomp function. Is there any detail about why the eigenvalues are zero in this case? Correct me if I'm wrong. The eigenvalues should be derived from covariance matrix which is based on variable dimensions. That is a n x n matrix that should theoritically give n eigenvalues of meaning.

Comment: The aim of PCA is to maximizing variance with ortogonality constrain and one way to solve this problem is using Lagrange multiplier(thus an eigenvalue problem). If you had more than min([m,n]) eigenvalues that are non-zero(assuming your data is mean-centered), this would mean you are spreading the variance rather than "compressing" them to the first scores. I think checking singular value decomposition would help you on the theory part since it solves eigenvalue problem for both covariance and correlation of X where the eigenvalues for both matrices are equal.